# What happens if Var args method also exists with overloaded methods exists in a Java method

Tags: java

Here is a program with method overloading done.

```
package com.tests;
public class BasicClass {

    public void getMe(Object a) {
        System.out.println("getMe 1");
    }

    public void getMe(Object a, Object b) {
        System.out.println("getMe 2");
    }

    public void getMe(Object a, Object b, Object c) {
        System.out.println("getMe 3");
    }

    public void getMe(Object a, Object b, Object c, Object d) {
        System.out.println("getMe 4");
    }

    public void getMe(Object... parms) {
        System.out.println("getMe 5");
    }
}
```

What is the exact benefit do we get with this type of polymorphism..?

Comment: You should also consider for this case varargs doesnt refer to 5+ objects, it will handle any null or 5+ call

Answer (score 3):

This is often done for optimization. It allows common operations (providing up to four values) to be performed without creating an array, whilst still giving the flexibility of allowing an arbitrary number of arguments.

To give a concrete, suppose we didn't have the first four overloads. In that case,

```
instance.getMe("a", "b");
```

would be converted by the compiler into:

```
instance.getMe(new Object[] { "a", "b" });
```

If the implementation doesn't *need* the arguments in an array, it's nice to avoid that array creation.

Comment: pardon my question, but this is the case for c# too, right?

Comment: @Eugene: Absolutely. That's why there are lots of overloads for `Console.WriteLine` for example.

Answer (score 2):

You get *one more* object in case of `var args` - which is an array implicitly. These concerns of creating more objects like this are valid only when your library **truly** cares about this. For example `jdk-9` methods like `Set.of` has overloaded methods that take up to 10 different arguments - without the need to create one extra array object.